# How to store the XML response that we got from using an api in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to use an api , and I send a request asking for some data using the javascript . The server replies back with an xml data , which I don't know where to store or how to access the XML . I can parse it using JSON , but need to know how to store the XML data first .

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What does XML have to do with JSON? What do you mean by "store" XML? Just keep a variable that references it. How about some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that API you're using requires some sort of authentication, don't use Javascript for that. It's client-side code and all authentication shows up in it.

Matt Ball is right; you cannot "parse it using JSON". You can however have a PHP script perform that task for you with its `xml_parser_*` functions.

Comment: I am using jsp here . So which function should I use ?